# I want to know why we are using 1st props?.heading and in <field why we r using heading=""

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React from "react";

import Field from "sleek-ui/Field";

import {InputStyle, Heading, SubHeading, DisplayHeading} from "./style";

const FieldComponent = (props) => {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            {props?.heading && <Heading> {props?.heading}</Heading>}
            {props?.subHeading && <SubHeading> {props?.subHeading}</SubHeading>}

            <Field
                {...props}
                heading=""
                subHeading=""
                displayName={<DisplayHeading>{props.displayName}</DisplayHeading>}
                styles={props.styles ? props.styles : InputStyle}
            />
        </React.Fragment>
    );
};

export default FieldComponent;
```

I want to know why we are using 1st props?.heading and in <field why we r using heading="" what is use of it and why its left empty

Comment: dont share images. copy that code and paste it here. It is more readable

Comment: yaa okay thanks for the advice will keep in my mind next time

Comment: yaa done can u please let me know the sol

Comment: yaa. check my solution below

Answer (score 0):

No. As the code is written, if there is no heading, you are not rendering the `Heading` element at all.

If you just do

```
<Heading> {props?.heading}</Heading>
```

Then you'll always render the heading element, sometimes with an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

This is a part of logical && operation. React provide us more useful mechanism for conditional rendering with this logical operators.

```
{props?.heading && <Heading> {props?.heading}</Heading>}
```

You can read above code as IF-Then condition. IF `props?.heading` exist THEN display content after && operator.

Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

As per the logic, it seems that the heading isnt supposed to be printed when it isnt there. So when you do

```
<heading>{props?.heading}</heading>
```

There will be a heading tag with no value in it. The space on the screen will still be occupied for it.
But, when you do this

```
props?.heading && <heading>props?.heading</heading>}
```

there will not even be the tag and no space consumed by it so that the UI stays clear.
Even I will recommend the way it is already there.